# Change django model from one app to another, but on makemigrations, new model is added

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I have two this model, which I want to move to another app.

After running this migration, I successfully could see the model under the required app.

But when I added another field, It was adding the entire model to the new migrations in new_app.

According to most tutorials, it should have added just the field.

I don't wanna fake the migrations, as it can cause issues.

Please point out my mistake.

Problem: On adding a new field in new_app model, the migrations has "CreateModel". How to avoid this?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Migrations are persisted on your db, there's a dedicated table that keeps the track of your changes. You shouldn't modify migrations directly.

My suggest:

- for development purpose you can delete your migration's files and migration's table.
- Try to create your migration once you moved your model If you can't delete anything,

then you should have something like.

```
users/0001_mymodel.py
users/0002_mymodel_deleted.py
otherapp/0001_mymodel_added.py
otherapp/0002_adding_field.py
```